# Registering a Domain Name automatically via a web service or API

Tags: domain-name, domain-registrar, domain-registration

Right now we have the need to register a new domain name every day or so.  As fun as going through godaddy's registration process is (or any domain registrar for that matter), we would like to automate the process.  Is there a registrar with some sort of web service or API that we can call into to perform the actual registration?  Ideally this would take care of all the legal agreements and they would have our billing information on file.

**Update**: recommendations for existing users is preferred and while reseller services fulfill this goal to a degree, a non reseller solution is preferred.

Comment: Are you a squatter?

Comment: no squatting, we provide website services for small businesses and the domain registration is part of the service for our customers.  automating it will help bring the domain registration more into the rest of our automated process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I googled for "domain registrar api", and came across several seemingly useful results:

- enom.com
- opensrs.com
- resellerclub.com
- dynadot.com
- joker.com
- domainpeople.com

And many others, so I suggest you use the power of Google to find one that suits you.

Comment: do you have any personal experience with these services?  Looking for a recommendation as well if youve used any.

Comment: No, I have not, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

My open source software (Net::DRI) is built in such a way that you could use it to plug various registrars API and have yourself locally a uniform and constant API whatever provider you choose, which is very handy if you need to switch providers or if you use more than one for various services.
Contact me if interested.

Also, completely separately, but if you start to register many domain names, you may wish to think about becoming a registrar yourself. You will then have to plug with registry systems, which means having an EPP client (and my software is an EPP client too!)